# How can I get a reference to the Adobe AIR Activity for an Android app?

Tags: java, android, air, android-intent

I have an Android app created with Adobe AIR and Flex. How can I get a reference to it's Activity so I can get it's intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("your.air.apps.package.goes.here");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

An alternative method would be to setup the Air app to handle URI schemes. [Defining custom URL schemes for your AIR mobile applications](http://www.riaspace.com/2011/08/defining-custom-url-schemes-for-your-air-mobile-applications/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+riaspace+%28Space+of+Flex%2FAIR+technologies%29) should help. The advantage of opening via a URI is you can send data from the native Android app to the Air one.